# Missing images after I redirect to a subdirectory using route.php and/or .htaccess in CodeIgniter Framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I redirected

> views/hello.php

to this url path, without creating a subdir:

> www.domain.com/subdir/hello

by using route.php

```
$route['subdir/hello'] = 'pages/view/hello';
```

however, some of the pictures that's inside hello.php were gone. I checked the "images" folder but it's still there.

I did check Inspect Element and there was an error:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

I've researched with this error but I didn't get any resolution. Without the redirection the images are still there. Please help.

Adding Edit:

This is also shown in the inspect element console error

```
GET http://p.nexac.com/e/sr/a-1548/s-3271/s-3271.xgi net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
getSegment.php?purl=http%3A%2F%2Fwwf.org.ph%2Fclimate-solutions&jsref=&rnd=1433844490975:1 
GET http://adadvisor.net/adscores/r.pixel?sid=9212270798 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
getSegment.php?purl=http%3A%2F%2Fwwf.org.ph%2Fclimate-solutions&jsref=&rnd=1433844490975:1
```

Comment: show your image link how you build it

Comment: You cannot access views directly in MVC, please elaborate your question

Comment: @Rejoanul Alam <img src="/images/wwd_climate-solutions.jpg" alt="Climate Solutions">

Comment: @Viral basically I was redirecting my "hello.php" to an imaginary subdirectory, making a new url path. But I couldn't bring the images to the new url path - therefore the error Resouce..... MIME type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

htacces or routing doesn't matter here. Your path is wrong. Use this, it will work everywhere

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('images/wwd_climate-solutions.jpg');?>" alt="Climate Solutions">
```

assuming that you do not make any change to config.php file's parameter `$config['base_url']`

Comment: Sorry about my reply, just checked that it was cached. Anyway, this worked! :) You rock @Rejoanul Alam ! :)